# Is there a way to show user PC datetime using a client-server chat?

Tags: php, mysql

Chat messages are stored in MySQL database. When a message is added it sets the current timestamp. If I want to save the local user datetime (from his computer - which can be invalid). How should I show that time to others users?

Also, when the user enters a chat the loaded messages can only show the saved time, nor the PC right?

Comment: Get it from the client through Javascript and save it in a separate column?

Comment: I don't understand, can you exaplain?

Comment: so where should I store them?

Comment: @yeah its me if you are making chat you should really use some XMPP server (ejabberd or Openfire). They have build in features for storing messages in db of your choice. AS far as your question goes why not use javascript, but  that is not really accurate because I can change my pc time. So long story short, I do not see the way that you can have 100% percent correct information on user time. I am always using this site for users data/time http://time.is/.